# How do you extract hierarchical data from XML into multidimensional arrays with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, hierarchy

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to do...

[**XML/Array sample**](http://i39.tinypic.com/2dbwbc2.png)

The closest example I could find was here:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

...but it doesn't show you how to put the data into variables/arrays.

---

Answer (score 0):

The XML file is just like the DOM tree, so you can select XML elements with jQuery very easily and put them in the array.